# Can not show limits below pi

Tags: equations

I am trying to write the following equation

[image]

I am using the code

```
  $PP(Path_i)=\prod_{L_k \in (Path_j)}{probability(L_k)}$
```

which is displaying the equation as

[image]

Please help.

Comment: limits come to the side in inline math, use `\[...\]` to get display math. also never use math italic for words, use `\mathit{Path}` and `\mathit{probability}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in a comment below your question, you have to use a displaystyle equation in order to have the limits (above and) below sums, products and integrals. Use `\[...]\` to get a displaystyle equation or, if you really want to have inline maths formated like displaystyle math, you can use `\displaystyle`.

I agree that you should use `\mathit` because without it it looks like a product of the variables P, a, t and h.

Maybe you are interested in `\mathclap` (requires `mathtools`) in order to save some horizontal space, but I think this is more a personal taste.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
   \[ PP(\mathit{Path}_i) = \prod_{L_k\in(\mathit{Path}_j)} \mathit{probability}(L_k) \]
   $\displaystyle PP(\mathit{Path}_i) = \prod_{\mathclap{L_k\in(\mathit{Path}_j)}} \mathit{probability}(L_k)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Inline one looks better.